# using conditionals in lambda functions

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I was going to use a lambda function that returns `'Purchase'` for not null values and returns `'No Purchase'` else. I am not be sure which one to use. If I use the first one it works. However, I can't understand why I have to use the first one instead of the second one.

```py
df['is_purchase'] = df.click_day.apply(lambda x: 'Purchase' if pd.notnull(x) else 'No Purchase')
```

```py
df['is_purchase'] = df.click_day.apply(lambda x: 'Purchase' if pd.notnull(x)==True else 'No Purchase')
```

Can someone please explain why the first one is true?

Comment: What is the problem, error message?

Comment: That is interesting, but why would you want to use the second variant anyway, when the first one is clearly better code?

Comment: `pd.notnull(x)==True` is implied by `pd.notnull(x)`, so the second is more wordy.

Comment: There is no error message. I was studying on a website, and this is a practice work. As an answer, it uses the first one. I just couldn't understand why the first one instead of the second.

Comment: So they both work the same way, then?

Comment: @cs95 oh okay. Does that only apply to this function or the general behavior of the lambda function?

Comment: Generally, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Because `if pd.notnull(x)==True` is bad style, in any programming language.  The `==True` is already implied, so why include it?

Answer (score 2):

If `something` has the logical value `True`, then the result of comparison it with `True`:

```
something == True
```

is `True`, too.

---

The opposite is true, too: If `something == True`, then `something` *has* the `True` logical value. So the form

```
if something:
```

means the same as

```
if something == True:
```

---

To understand why the shortest form is preferred, compare

```
if (a < 10) == True:
```

with

```
if a < 10:
```

Which one is more natural?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a visual example of what has already been explained:

```
In [45]: s = pd.Series([True, False])

In [46]: s
Out[46]: 
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool

In [47]: s2 = s == True

In [48]: s2
Out[48]: 
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool

In [49]: s.equals(s2)
Out[49]: True
```

Saying `if some_bool` is the same as saying `if some_bool == True`, so there's no need to type it out explicitly.